# How to include file while building to linux using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-linux

I have `.so` file and I useing it with `ffi` in separated flutter package.

In my project's `pubspec.yaml` under `dependencies` I imported the package like this

```yaml
virtual_controller:
    path: packages/virtual_controller
```

the question is how to build the c code to `.so` at the build time of my project and provide it with the linux released executable file.